# OpenLayers 4.6.5 blurs image with raster source

Tags: openlayers

It is observed that when i use imaeStatic as a source to image layer then image does not blur but when i use Raster then it does.

```
// Image Static
const imageSource = new ImageStatic({
      projection: this.projection,
      imageExtent: this.extent,
      imageSize: [imageWidth, imageHeight],
      url: imageURL,
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    })

// Setting source to image layer
imageLayer.setSource(imageSource);
```

[image: Image without blur]

Now,
If i add a raster Source, same image becomes bit bulry.

```
// Image Static
const imageSource = new ImageStatic({
      projection: this.projection,
      imageExtent: this.extent,
      imageSize: [imageWidth, imageHeight],
      url: imageURL,
      crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'
    })

// Raster
const raster = new Raster({
      sources: [imageSource],
      operation: (pixels, data) => {
        // (Brightness and contrast operation)
        return response;
      },
      lib: {
        truncateColor: truncateColor,
        getBrightness: getBrightness,
        getContrast: getContrast
      }
    });

// Setting raster source
imageLayer.setSource(raster);
```

[image: Image with blur]

I am not able to understand this behaviour and not sure how it can be fixed.
Any suggestions?

Note : After adding a raster source, even if i don't make changes in pixel, it still loads blur image.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use `imageSmoothingEnabled` directly with 4.6.5 version. To address this issue, I created a one more Image layer for raster source.
Now when i want to make use of image pixels, then i used to set visibility of raster source.

```
const imageLayer = new ImageLayer({})
imageLayer.setSource(ImageStaticSource);

const rasterImageLayer = new ImageLayer({})
rasterImageLayer.setSource(RasterSource);

if(need image pixels) {
   rasterImageLayer.setVisible(true);
   imageLayer.setVisible(false);
}
else {
   rasterImageLayer.setVisible(false);
   imageLayer.setVisible(true);
}
```